# React Js - How to make nav link active on click

Tags: reactjs

I am new to Reactjs,I have created a navigation/header page but active class is not working properly when I click on navigation link. I am using navlink tag here with dynamic class.
Problem - All the links are showing active always. Here is the code below

### PortalNavbar.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Button, Nav } from "react-bootstrap";
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';
import { useNavigate, Outlet, NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import '../../index.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min';

const PortalNavbar = () => {

    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const logout = () => {
        localStorage.clear();
        navigate('/auth/login');
    }

    return (
        <React.Fragment>

            <header>
                <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-white navbar-light">
                    <div className="container-fluid">
                        <ul className="navbar-nav">
                            <li className="nav-item">
                                <NavLink exact="true" className="nav-link logoheader mx-3" to='/' >REACT.COM
                                </NavLink>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item">
                                <NavLink exact="true" className={(navData) => (navData.isActive ? "active nav-link mx-3" : 'nav-link mx-3')} to='/' >Home</NavLink>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item">
                                <NavLink className={(navData) => (navData.isActive ? "active nav-link mx-3" : 'nav-link mx-3')} to='/dashboard'>Dashboard</NavLink>
                            </li>

                            <li className="nav-item">
                                <Button className="btn-warning" onClick={logout}>Logout</Button>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </header>
        </React.Fragment>

    );
}

export default PortalNavbar;
```

### index.css

```
.active {
  border-bottom: 2px #61dafb solid;
  padding-bottom: 3px;

}

.nav-link {
  color: #000 !important;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-left: 0 !important;
  padding-right: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this kind of the problem to solve you might try the snippet as below for more of the pages. The below of the code only works for dashboard.

```
import {  useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
   let location = useLocation(); 
   <li className="nav-item">
  <NavLink className={`nav-link ${location.pathname === "/dashboard" ? "active" : ""}`}  to='/dashboard'>Dashboard</NavLink>
     </li>
```

This might help you to solve your problem .

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way I have found is:

In the navbar component:
const styles = ({ isActive }) => ({ color: isActive ? '#FFF' : '#929292' });

and then on your navlinks, you can add the style={styles}

With your code:

```
import React from "react";
import { Button, Nav } from "react-bootstrap";
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';
import { useNavigate, Outlet, NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import '../../index.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min';

const styles = ({ isActive }) => ({ color: isActive ? '#DAF7A6' : '#CD5C5C' });

const PortalNavbar = () => {

    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const logout = () => {
        localStorage.clear();
        navigate('/auth/login');
    }

    return (
        <React.Fragment>

            <header>
                <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-white navbar-light">
                    <div className="container-fluid">
                        <ul className="navbar-nav">
                            <li className="nav-item">
                                <NavLink style={styles} exact="true" className="nav-link logoheader mx-3" to='/react' >REACT.COM</NavLink>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item">
                                <NavLink style={styles} exact="true" className={(navData) => (navData.isActive ? "active nav-link mx-3" : 'nav-link mx-3')} to='/' >Home</NavLink>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item">
                                <NavLink style={styles} className={(navData) => (navData.isActive ? "active nav-link mx-3" : 'nav-link mx-3')} to='/dashboard'>Dashboard</NavLink>
                            </li>

                            <li className="nav-item">
                                <Button className="btn-warning" onClick={logout}>Logout</Button>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </header>
        </React.Fragment>

    );
}

export default PortalNavbar;
```

Comment: Same issue , when I click on a nav link,clicked link is getting active but still other link having active class , it is not getting removed.

Comment: Hey I just tried it with your code and it worked for me, Do you mean the react.com link is  changing with the home? That would be because theyre both linked to '/'.

Comment: I mean active class is not getting remove. All the link is getting active. For ex - suppose if I click Home it is active ,then if I go to Dashboard link ,Dashboard is getting active but Home is not getting inactive

Comment: In that case, you can use state to change the className and toggle between the active class and inactive class by using a handleclick function.